# iPhone keeps sending apple-site-association requests

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, applet

Not sure if here is the right place to ask this, sorry if not.

Today I've set up my iPhone to use Fiddler as proxy and then saw that it makes requests to /.well-known/apple-site-association for applications.

I know it's for a purpose but the weird thing is it keeps sending same request for lots of apps (and for every country domain for apps like Tripadvisor) and like in an infinite loop. Again and again for same app and domains and doesn’t stop doing that. I saw that once before too. When I restart the phone it stops.

[image: Screenshot for requests]

What can be the reason for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your example does not show multiple requests for the same file? It's always variants, but nether exactly the same file...

Comment: @KevinGriesbach it keeps requesting same domains, same files... like in an infinite loop. Hard to put all of them here...

Answer (score 0):

iPhone sends these requests to download files from each domain which tells the iphone which apps support which universal links. 
If you look at the description from the following URL you can see that this company has two apps which supports the following URL's which can be directly opened inside the app instead of being re-directing to web pages.

So if you encounter anywhere on your phone the link "www.ixigo.com/flights" (lets say in a message in whatsapp)it iOS will straight away open the app as the app supports these url.

Similarly if an APP supports multiple domains, iOS will make multiple hits and download all the urls which the app supports.
https://www.ixigo.com/apple-app-site-association

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
         "appID": "6WCD67RXUP.com.ixigo.travel",
         "paths": [
            "/flights",
            "/hotels",
            "/holiday-tour-packages",
            "/holiday-tour-packages",
            "/restaurants",
            "/ixigoer",
            "/near-me",
            "/send-enquiry",
            "/ixigomoney"
          ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "6WCD67RXUP.com.ixigo.trains",
        "paths" : [
          "/trains",
          "/search/result/train/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually my question was more about why it does that in an infinite loop? same requests for same app and doesn’t stop doing that.

Comment: Is the only way to stop these requests to delete the app that is causing them?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Web Browser–to–Native App Handoff.

User activities can be shared among apps that are signed with the same developer team identifier and supporting a given activity type. If an app is document-based, it can opt to support Handoff automatically

[Read More Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10)